# Importance of osculating plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

In the class, i learn that there are three kinds of planes, osculating, normal, rectifying which is perpendicular, B, T, N.

The prof. says that especially osculating plane is important. 
I wonder why this osculating plane plays a crucial role in differential geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander Brodsky (not to be confused with the famous Russian architect by that name) gives a nice exposition of the physical meaning of the osculating plane here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coahLyiATuA

Comment: wow good!  It helps me a lot